# I'm working on drowsiness detection project and getting an exception on tkinter call back and unable to open shape predictor file

Tags: tkinter, dlib

'**init.py**'

```py
class CallWrapper:
    """Internal class. Stores function to call when some user
    defined Tcl function is called e.g. after an event occurred."""
    def __init__(self, func, subst, widget):
        """Store FUNC, SUBST and WIDGET as members."""
        self.func = func
        self.subst = subst
        self.widget = widget
    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Apply first function SUBST to arguments, than FUNC."""
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.widget._report_exception()
```

**error**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiTnw.png

Comment: Are you sure that "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" is in the correct folder?

Comment: yes I'm sure  the shape predictor is in the correct folder

Comment: Try using the full path to the file ("C:\Users\Murugan\...\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

Comment: please avoid using links to images with errors. you should copy paste them in SO

Comment: I try using the full path still' m getting  the  same error